# Speed seems random with constant impulse

Tags: box2d

I'm shooting an object from the top vertex of a triangle using Box2dWeb. The issue I'm having is that the projectile speed seems to be fairly random, even with `applyimpulse` set to a constant. The gravity is set to zero.

I thought it could be the physics step, changing these settings hasn't made a difference. The projectile will shoot out at very very fast speeds, then it will shoot out at its defined speed.

```
bodyman[0].GetBody().ApplyForce(
    bodyman[0].GetBody().GetWorldVector(new b2Vec2(0,-50)),
    bodyman[0].GetBody().GetWorldCenter());
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling ApplyForce?

Comment: something was choking the update loop and effecting the iterations per second, strange but its resolved..